# OAuth 2 with Google API

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

Google API supports OAuth 2.0 authentication with `redirect_uri` to either `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` (an access token will be displayed in the browser and needs to be copy-pasted) or to the `localhost` for installed apps. In the later case, as said in the documentation, I need to up a temporary web server! Why I can't get the token in a plain response? Say, JSON? Why are these complications with the web server? Can I workaround somehow this? Is there a way to get the token without copy/paste and the web server on the localhost? How does it work with the localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found in the doc: When this value is used, your application can sense that the page has loaded and the title of the HTML page contains the authorization code. So, I should monitor for particular page title.

Answer (score 0):

redirect_uri are validated by Google API server when a request for access token is sent from the client application!

Any mismatch of these URL's will result a failure response.